# Oops. It is not possible to have the merge start hidden

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the message "Oops. It is not possible to have the merge start hidden" after a script has finished execution.

The script hides any column in a range which have their title field blank and show those that are not empty. I have found out that if some of the columns have a vertical merge to them and that causes the trouble. This is the link for the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AphsvceI4elpdGtTSWwtalFpT2xkUWxvNDV1cVZ1S1E&usp=sharing

The script code is:

```
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var customColumnsRanges = activeSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("TheseOnes");

function resetColumnsVisibilityIfNotBlank() {

  var sheet = customColumnsRanges.getSheet()
  var column = customColumnsRanges.getColumn();
  var length = customColumnsRanges.getWidth();
  var customColumns = customColumnsRanges.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {

    if (customColumns[0][i] == "") {
      sheet.hideColumns(column);
    } else {
      sheet.showColumns(column);
    }

    ++column;

  }

}
```

If this cells are unmerged then there is no problem. If I do that manually then again there is no problem, but I need to have this functionality automatically. If someone can help me solve this that would be great!

Comment: Hi.....Your sheet is view only...whereby the script cannot be viewed....

Comment: @Vasim couldn't get it to show so I have posted the script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Range.breakapart()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#breakApart%28%29) to unmerge, before hiding the column. You need to get a range to operate on - in this example, we're using [`Range.offset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset%28Integer,Integer,Integer%29) to select a column. Note that it's selecting all the cells from the `customColumnsRanges` row to the bottom of the sheet.

```
    ...
    if (customColumns[0][i] == "") {
      // Get a range containing just this column, and break apart any merges.
      var columnRange = customColumnsRanges.offset(0,i,sheet.getMaxRows()-customColumnsRanges.getRow());
      columnRange.breakApart();
      sheet.hideColumns(column);
      Logger.log('Hiding column ' + column);
    } else {
    ...
```